# jQuery .is() method performance

Tags: javascript, jquery

How does the jQuery `.is()` method actually work?

The official [API](http://api.jquery.com/is/) documentation says:

> Starting with jQuery 1.7, selector strings with positional selectors
>   apply the selector against the document, and then determine whether
>   the first element of the current jQuery set matches any of the
>   resulting elements. So for the HTML shown above, an expression such as
>   `$( "li:first" ).is( "li:last" )` returns `false`.

So, if I have this HTML markup:

```
<div id="foo">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
</div >
<div id="bar">
    <span>1/1</span>
    <span>2/2</span>
    <span>3/3</span>
</div >
```

and in my script element I will do:

```
$('#foo span').is('span') /* I know, this example is stupid and has 
        nothing to do with the real world, but I want to know the essence */
```

so then `.is()` method actually would select **all** `span` elements in the document, even bar's ones. And if I want to increase performance I should do:
`$('#foo span').is('#foo span')` to narrow the matched set? Is this correct or not?

Comment: `span` won't select any `li` elements. Please review your question and make sure your example markup matches the code you're asking about. As it is it's unclear what exactly you're asking.

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @zzzzBov I edited, sorry about that

Comment: If it's just performance you want to measure, visit http://jsperf.com and run your test in multiple browsers.

Comment: @Blazemonger not browser compatibility, but performance - time in which code runs more smoothly

Comment: Yes, but different browsers have different JavaScript engines and may have different performance results. In any event, write your own test and see the results for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that algorithmically, there is a performance hit to passing a broad selector to the `is` method.

To perform this test, jQuery must select every element in the document that matches this selector. From there it must perform a linear search, testing if each element that it just selected matches the first element in the collection it was called on.

This means the search is O(N) complexity, as the worst case scenario means that it may have to iterate over all the elements `is` selected (if the last element is the one that matches, or none match). This means that the linear search time for this method will increase linearly with each element that matches.

Additionally, if `is` is called on a collection of elements it will have to repeat this search for each element in the initial collection. In fact, jQuery's implementation will actually continue to perform this search even after a match is found.

This brings our total search complexity up to O(N*M), where N represents elements selected by N, and M represents the collection being tested.

As always, the proof is in the source.

Here we see where the `is` selector is passed to the usual `jQuery` function.

#### Excerpt from [`src/traversing/findFilter.js`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/99e8ff1baa7ae341e94bb89c3e84570c7c3ad9ea/src/traversing/findFilter.js#L83-L94)

```
    is: function( selector ) {
        return !!winnow(
            this,

            // If this is a positional/relative selector, check membership in the returned set
            // so $("p:first").is("p:last") won't return true for a doc with two "p".
            typeof selector === "string" && rneedsContext.test( selector ) ?
                jQuery( selector ) :
                selector || [],
            false
        ).length;
    }
```

And in the `winnow` function, we find where is performs the search.

#### Excerpt from [`src/traversing/findFilter.js`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/99e8ff1baa7ae341e94bb89c3e84570c7c3ad9ea/src/traversing/findFilter.js#L35-L37)

```
    return jQuery.grep( elements, function( elem ) {
        return ( indexOf.call( qualifier, elem ) > -1 ) !== not;
    } );
```

First it filters the selected elements by looping ove them and checking if the elements appears in the `is` selection using `indexOf`, which performs a linear search.

Of course, you will have to weight the benefits of more-complex code against performance benefits. In many cases, it may be better to use alternative means of determining if an elements meats your criteria, like `hasClass` or `prop`.

Answer (score 4):

`is` will internally iterate the set that matches the given selector. You can look for yourself at two spots in their source code at https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js . Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and search for "is:" or "winnow" to find these two snippets.

- `is`

  ```
  is: function( selector ) {
   return !!winnow(
   this,
   // If this is a positional/relative selector, check membership in the returned set
   // so $("p:first").is("p:last") won't return true for a doc with two "p".
   typeof selector === "string" && rneedsContext.test( selector ) ?
      jQuery( selector ) :
          selector || [],
          false
   ).length;
  }
  ```
- winnow

  ```
  function winnow( elements, qualifier, not ) {
      if ( jQuery.isFunction( qualifier ) ) {
          return jQuery.grep( elements, function( elem, i ) {
              /* jshint -W018 */
              return !!qualifier.call( elem, i, elem ) !== not;
          });

      }

      if ( qualifier.nodeType ) {
          return jQuery.grep( elements, function( elem ) {
              return ( elem === qualifier ) !== not;
          });

      }

      if ( typeof qualifier === "string" ) {
          if ( risSimple.test( qualifier ) ) {
              return jQuery.filter( qualifier, elements, not );
          }

          qualifier = jQuery.filter( qualifier, elements );
      }

      return jQuery.grep( elements, function( elem ) {
          return ( indexOf.call( qualifier, elem ) >= 0 ) !== not;
      });
  }
  ```

What you should glean from these two snippets is that they are always constructing a new jQuery object from the selector. The result of this construction is that the DOM is queried for the matching elements in the selector. Then the matching set is filtered through looking for the original element this was all called on. If the resulting set has a match (length) then true is returned.

So that is what is going on there.

- Does it make sense to reduce the size of the matching set to ensure that the `is` has better performance? Yes.
- Is it a microoptimization? In most cases it will be. If there are more than 10,000 elements on the page for this to be an optimization then there are more than likely other issues that need addressing anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the above answers ignore the conditional:  `rneedsContext.test(selector)`

jQuery **only** enumerates if the above condition evaluates to *true*.  `rneedsContext` is the following regular expression:

```
new RegExp( "^" + whitespace + "*[>+~]|:(even|odd|eq|gt|lt|nth|first|last)(?:\\(" + whitespace + "*((?:-\\d)?\\d*)" + whitespace + "*\\)|)(?=[^-]|$)", "i" )
```

From the look of it, this expression matches only for selectors that begin with these characters: `>+~:`.  For example, `$.is('span')` will not enumerate, while `$.is(':first')` will.

In summary, jQuery `:is` is smart and only enumerates elements when it *has* to; in other words it is as efficient as it can be, and you should use without much worry.